# How to export grease pencil's layers to another Blender file?

Tags: export, blend-files, layers, grease-pencil

I want to export all grease pencil layers in a Blender file into another file, because I need to merge some drawings in one animation, but can't find any options to export Grease Pencil layers.

Additionally I no want to convert the grease pencil layers into a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, because the program freeze and can't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using *Link* or *Append Data Block* from Blender file, on the *File* menu.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the side panel of grease pencil in 3d view there are two ways of setting the data source of grease pencil strokes. It could be scene or object, if you set at the beginning the source to be the scene, that's the default, you have to append the whole scene, otherwise you have to append the object that has stored the grease pencil data.

[image]