# How to bring Grease Pencil drawings to another .blend file? - 2.80

Tags: grease-pencil

First off, I understand there's this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66528/how-to-export-grease-pencils-layers-to-another-blender-file), but it's older than 2 years now.
I tried Appending but only an empty Grease Pencil data arrives.
In the original I have 4 keyframes. Only one keyframe arrives, without the drawings.

I tried today’s release.
Should I try exporting it?
If so, under what format?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by copying the GPencil item from the Outliner, and pasting it to the new file.
So now I know this can be done this way.

What sucks is that I was doing this in the hope that the Onion Skinning effect would be restored, but it wasn't. It seems the Onion Skinning effect got affected when I imported an image to draw over.